# How can I match the content inside a couple of parenthesis with regex if there are inner parenthesis?

Tags: java, regex

The problem I want to solve is the following:
I have this string as input:

Hello World: [[DATA.[field]]] something else

the group I want to catch is:

DATA.[field]

The problem is that I want to catch whatever is inside "[[" and "]]".

What is the regex I should use in Java?
Thanks

Comment: For the case of this string, a simple greedy match would work: `"\\[\\[(.*)\\]\\]"`. However, you can't, in general, find matching parentheses using regular expressions.

Comment: Elaborating on Andy's comment, it is discouraged to use regex to parse markup and generally, language with nested structures.

Comment: To precise a bit: it is impossible to use recursion and balanced constructs in Java regex.

Comment: Guys, here use case is simple enough so regex will not be an issue. OP is not asking to parse complex `JSON` or  `C` or `C` inspired languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following regex:

```
(?<=\[\[).*?(?=\]\](\s|$))
```

Example:

```
String text = "Hello World: [[DATA.[field]]] something else";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[\\[).*?(?=\\]\\](\\s|$))", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(text);

if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

From sample data string, it will print

```
DATA.[field]
```

Comment: It does work fine with the sample, but more specifically if I have just: [[DATA.[field]]] as input your regex doesn't work anymore